# Is this right query to be sent to Oracle

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

`UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COL_1=?, COL_2=? where COL_3=? AND COL_4=?`

and I send exact number of values in array to the Statement(In my case  : 4). Doing so I am getting exception : Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 4

Note : I think we cannot DO `SET COL_1=?,COL_2=?` we need to do `SET COL_1='DESIRED_VALUE',COL_2='DESIRED_VALUE'` Is this my misconception?

Java Code

```
StringBuilder updateQuery=new StringBuilder("UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COL_1=?, COL_2=? where BOOKMARKID_ACT=? AND DIMID_ACT=?");         
ArrayList<Object> alObjectData=new ArrayList<Object>();
alObjectData.add("VALUE1");
alObjectData.add("VALUE2");
alObjectData.add("VALUE3");
alObjectData.add("VALUE4");
dpQuery.executeUpdate(connTemp, updateQuery.toString(), alObjectData);
```

Comment: It sounds like you're just not providing enough parameters...

Comment: And the code of dpQuery.executeUpdate() is...?

Comment: Error stacktrace and code snippet from your `executeUpdate(conn...` can help analysing the error.

Comment: What is the datatype of all four cols. If they are of type varchar than you should do this '?'

Comment: @ejb_guy they are all of type varchar and I tried doing it but am getting same exception

Comment: @ejb_guy: provided a prepared statement is used behind the scene, there should be no quote around the parameters. But without code, impossible to help.

Comment: Hope you have also tried sending single quote with values i.e. "'value1'" Can you provide complete class name of dbQuery

Comment: What is the 'type' of `dpQuery`. A quick glance at the APIs for `Statement` doesn't show any calls that take 3 parameters (Connection, String, List).

Comment: @JB Nizet - yeap agree. my suggestion was based on that arraylist is of type Object. I am not sure how this will be interpreted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want to create a `PreparedStatement`. It should looked like this:

```
// con is your active connection

String sqlStatement = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COL_1=?, COL_2=? where BOOKMARKID_ACT=? AND DIMID_ACT=?";
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
prest.setString(1, valueFirstParam);
prest.setString(2, valueSecondParam);
prest.setString(3, valueThirdParam);
prest.setString(4, valueFourthParam);
prest.executeUpdate();
```

you should also add this line on top of the class

```
import java.sql.*;
```

*PreparedStatements avoid your code from sql injection.*

**[more on this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)**